# Coinbase pool smart contract code

Tags: solidity, vyper

What is this contract and where can I find its code? `https://etherscan.io/address/0xa9d1e08c7793af67e9d92fe308d5697fb81d3e43#code`

It looks like it was deployed by Coinbase. However, I don't see any similar repos on their GitHub